# color in apk is diiferent from android emulator

Tags: android, colors, textview, cardview

this is my android studio emulator screenshot

and this is my phone same app apk format screenshot
[image]
cardview colors is different in apk format
also textview colors are also different

this problem is happens in every app made my me

my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_screen_content_background_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/main_screen_content_padding"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_view_elevation">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_view_content_padding">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_main"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/identification_image_marginEnd"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/snowflake" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_main"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/label_text_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Weather" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_main_description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/value_text_size"
                        tools:text="condition" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_view_elevation">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_view_content_padding">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_humidity"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/identification_image_marginEnd"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/humidity" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_temp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/label_text_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Degree" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_humidity"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/value_text_size"
                        tools:text="per cent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_view_marginTop"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_view_elevation">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_view_content_padding">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_min_max"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/identification_image_marginEnd"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/temperature" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_min"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/label_text_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Minimum" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_max"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/value_text_size"
                        tools:text="Maximum" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_view_elevation">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_view_content_padding">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_wind"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/identification_image_marginEnd"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/wind" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_speed"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/label_text_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Wind" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_speed_unit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="@string/miles_per_hour"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/value_text_size" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_view_marginTop"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_view_marginStartEnd"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_view_elevation">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/card_view_content_padding">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_location"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/identification_image_marginEnd"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/location" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/label_text_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Name" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_country"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/value_text_size"
                        tools:text="Country" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/divider_margin"
                android:background="@color/divider_background" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/sunrise_marginTop"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_sunrise"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/identification_image_marginEnd"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sunrise" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_sunrise_time"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/value_text_size"
                        tools:text="Sunrise" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sunset_marginStart"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_sunset"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/identification_image_size"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/identification_image_marginEnd"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sunset" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_sunset_time"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/value_text_size"
                        tools:text="Sunset" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

WAITING FOR AN EARLY RESPONSE THANK U

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is likely in dark mode, and this is what's causing the color differences. This is happening because your app's theme supports both light and dark modes. You can actually set the preview window in Android Studio to dark mode if you want.

Also, a quick fix for the bottoms of your `CardView`s being cut off is to add `useCompatPadding="true"` to each one.